# Calculating Electric Field from a Potential Difference w/o Charge

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, electrostatics, electric-fields, capacitance

So here is my homework question:

> *Two long cylindrical shells of metal (radii $r_1$ and $r_2$, $r_2 > r_1$) are arranged coaxially. The plates are maintained at the potential difference $\Delta\phi$. The region between the shells is filled with a medium of conductivity $g$. Use Ohm's law, $J = gE$, to calculate the electric current between unit lengths of the shells.*

So I understand how to go from the current density to the actual current, but I need to find the electric field $E$ in order to find the current density $J$. I am not given the charges on each cylinder. How do I calculate the $E$ field when I am only given a potential difference? I know $\Delta\phi = \int E\,\mathrm{d}\ell$ but I feel like that doesn't help me much.

Comment: What if you postulated some charge $\lambda $ per unit length, found the electric field (using e.g. Gauss' law), calculated the potential difference, and then solved for $\lambda $ in terms of $\Delta\phi $?

Comment: @Emilio I think that would make a good answer (considering that it's a homework question).

Comment: Ah I see what your saying. I'll try that and see what I come up with. I'm still curious about whether or not its actually possible to find the electric field with only the information I'm given or if, like you said, I have to postulate a charge distribution. If I'm not mistaken there physically has to be some sort of distribution, but I wonder whether or not it is necessary information.

Comment: @DavidZ Yes, but I'm on a tablet right now and latex is un.be.lie.va.bly painful. If this doesn't have an answer tomorrow I'll write one up. In the meantime,  I suggest Mr Frobenius give my suggestions a try.

Comment: @Mr.Frobenius you can indeed sidestep the charge distribution entirely. You should postulate and solve Laplace's equation for the potential, for which you have enough information. From that you can get the electric field and the current density. Curiously, the current should actually be proportional to the charge.

Comment: @Emilio No, I meant literally the _exact same text_ you  posted as a comment should have been posted as an answer IMO. I'm not saying you should post a full explanation of how such a calculation would work - in fact, an answer like that would be a violation of our homework policy.

Comment: Do you mean the current shouldn't be proportional to the charge? I used your method, which worked quite well by the way, and I came out with the correct answer. However my current is not proportional to the charge. Wasn't the idea to eliminate the charge distribution from the electric field equation in the first place?

Comment: Oh! I see what your saying now. Instead of postulating a charge distribution, using Gauss' law to find the potential, then solving for the distribution in terms of the known potential difference, you meant use Laplace's equation and the boundary conditions given to find the solution in cylindrical coordinates.